# Hacking Rust security approach

Tags: security, rust

The Rust compiler checks for lots of security issues (e.g. the borrow checker, ownership rules, etc.) and prevents insecure code from even compiling. This is amazing.

However, what if hackers who want to publish malware compile the code using their own manipulated compilers which do not check for any of those rules anymore?

There will be lots of Rust crates in repositories soon and developers are relying on their code's security just because of the Rust compiler.

Comment: These hackers of yours, they don't need to modify the rust compiler. They can simply use unsafe.

Comment: Hackers do not, in general, have the ability to run arbitrary code on your computer. If they do, well, you're right: the compiler will not stop them. But that's not what people are usually talking about when they discuss security vulnerabilities in code. Consider [Heartbleed](https://xkcd.com/1354/), which is a buffer overflow in the *server* (trusted code) which an attacker can exploit by sending a contrived request (untrusted input).

Comment: Safety and security are two different things. Rust's safety is mainly for protecting programmers against programming mistakes. Such mistakes may lead to security issues. The aim of Rust is to provide safety, but this is does not mean it's not possible to write malicious software in rust (unintentionally or intentionally).

Comment: There is a great article that talks about what security issues Rust does solve and what does not. Rust addresses 7 out of the top 25 security vulnerabilities. https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/blog/rust-software-security-a-current-state-assessment/

Answer (score 8):

The problem of users getting shady binaries from untrusted sources is completely orthogonal to Rust's promise of memory and thread safety.

Rust aims to make it harder to accidentally write buggy code that could be exploited by a hacker, not to make it impossible to write malicious code.

Answer (score 1):

All crates from crates.io are compiled again when you use them, so it is impossible for a crate author to introduce memory unsafety that way.

Of course, if a crate uses `unsafe` code, then it's up to you to be comfortable with what the author has done.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down:

> We know that the Rust compiler will check for lots of security issues (e.g. Borrow check, Ownership rules, etc) and prevent insecure code even to be compiled. This is amazing.

Yes, this is true. The Rust compiler will enforce type and memory safety.

> However, what if hackers who want to publish sort of malsoftwares, compile the codes using their own version of manipulated compilers which do not check for any of those rules anymore?

If you download a crate that was published on [crates.io](https://crates.io/), the crate will be recompiled locally. It is true that downloaded crates may use `unsafe` code that avoids some memory safety enforcement.

In the case of downloading a binary directly off the internet (not through crates.io), you cannot be sure that what you are downloading is what is says it is. In fact, a file marked as a Rust library may in fact be a virus written in assembly. This problem has nothing to do with Rust, or any other language.

> There will be lots of Rust crates and libs on the repositories soon and developers are relying on their code's security just because of Rust compiler.

This not true. Developers may be relying on the type and memory safety of their code that is enforced by the compiler. However, just because the compiler enforces safety within you code does not mean that you it will stop viruses or malware from infecting your device. Anything that you download off the internet can potentially harm your device, regardless of the language.

Comment: _"you cannot use an unsafe dependency without knowing beforehand"_ actually you can. For example the standard library has a lot of unsafe internals that are wrapped in "safe" APIs so that you can use them without marking your code "unsafe". So do several crates on crates.io.